# deploy netbeans Java EE web project

Tags: deployment, netbeans, jakarta-ee

Hi
I am new to deploying web projects. I want to deploy my Java EE Netbeans project on a different remote server. I just kept the .war file in the tomcat webapp folder and it worked fine. But I could not see the images and CSS effects in the webpage. How do I bundle my images, CSS files, scripts etc. in the .war file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Netbeans web application project there is a folder *WebPages* under the project node. You can for example create a folder *resources* (right click on *WebPages* --> new folder) and put all your images, css files and scripts in it.

Then they are automatically included in the war.

(The *WebPages* folder in the project window is mapped to the *project-name/web* on file system.)

Comment: I have the same setup you mentioned, looks like the war file was not packaged properly. I have some Java classes in "Source Packages" folder. The JSP pages are using these Java classes and their methods, But these java classes are not in the war file. How do I package these classes?

Comment: You could check the project settings (right click on project node --> settings). Check the "Sources" node and the "Build->Packaging" node.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into this document: http://www.examulator.com/moodle/mod/resource/view.php?id=455 and see how it works instead of relying only on the IDE provided features, then use the IDE (like Netbeans) build the project and see the war file which IDE created for you.